# Angular ngFor IntelliSense Shows 'any' Instead of the Type in visual studio code

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

**Question:**

When using `ngFor` in my Angular template to loop through a Person array, the type of the variable `person` is displayed as `any` instead of its actual type. How can I ensure proper type recognition for `person` within the loop

[image]

[image]

**Code:**

sample.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

class Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;

  constructor(name: string, age: number) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-sample',
  templateUrl: './sample.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sample.component.scss']
})
export class SampleComponent implements OnInit {

  personArray: Person[];
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const person1 = new Person("Alice", 30);
    const person2 = new Person("Bob", 25);

    this.personArray = [person1, person2];
    
  }

}
```

sample.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let person of personArray">
  {{person.name}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this message find you well.

To enable the type checking, you can add the `strictTemplates` option in your `tsconfig.json` like this:

```
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
```

for more information please check here: https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck

and the configurations here: https://angular.io/guide/typescript-configuration

[image]

[image]